# Subtracting mean of columns with groupby across multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I am having trouble applying this function with a  groupby in multiple columns, but skipping certain columns.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
arr = pd.DataFrame(
[[201207310930, 0.0022, -0.0160,    0.0055, 0.0324, -0.0328],
[201207310930,  0.0040, -0.0073,    0.0293, 0.0465, -0.0275],   
[201207310930,  -0.0095,-0.0080,    0.0215, 0.0525, -0.0317],   
[201207311030,  -0.0005,-0.0040,    -0.0149,    0.0135, 0.0488],
[201207311030,  -0.0087,-0.0240,    0.0134, 0.0480, -0.0331]]
)
```

I'd like to group on datetime and then de-trend (subtract the mean), so this is what I have tried (ignoring x1 column):

```
detrendfunc = lambda x: (x - x.mean())
cols = arr.columns[2:]
output=df.groupby(['Datetime'])[cols].transform(detrendfunc)
```

My problem is that this is just outputting a bunch of zeros, I think its just subtracting x from the mean of x, but the mean of x only includes the one element, not the group of elements.

The expected result is a new dataframe that has the mean of each group in each column subtracted from each element:

```
201207310930    0.0033  -0.00556    -0.01326    -0.0114 -0.00213
201207310930    0.0051  0.00313      0.01053    0.0027  0.00316
201207310930    -0.0084 0.00243      0.00273    0.0087  -0.001033
201207311030    0.0041  0.01        -0.01415    -0.01725  0.04095
201207311030    -0.0041 -0.01        0.01415    0.01725 -0.04095
```

Comment: What is inside variable `arr`?

Comment: the dataframe with Datetime, x1, x2...x5

Comment: Can you edit your code and put there expected result?

Comment: OK I have added the expected result and shown how to create arr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have this `df`:

```
       Datetime      x1      x2      x3      x4      x5
0  201207310930  0.0022 -0.0160  0.0055  0.0324 -0.0328
1  201207310930  0.0040 -0.0073  0.0293  0.0465 -0.0275
2  201207310930 -0.0095 -0.0080  0.0215  0.0525 -0.0317
3  201207311030 -0.0005 -0.0040 -0.0149  0.0135  0.0488
4  201207311030 -0.0087 -0.0240  0.0134  0.0480 -0.0331
```

Then:

```py
detrendfunc = lambda x: (x - x.mean())
cols = df.columns[1:]  # <-- change `arr` to `df` and `[2:]` to `[1:]`
output = df.groupby(["Datetime"])[cols].transform(detrendfunc)

df_out = pd.concat([df["Datetime"], output], axis=1)
print(df_out)
```

Prints:

```
       Datetime      x1        x2        x3       x4        x5
0  201207310930  0.0033 -0.005567 -0.013267 -0.01140 -0.002133
1  201207310930  0.0051  0.003133  0.010533  0.00270  0.003167
2  201207310930 -0.0084  0.002433  0.002733  0.00870 -0.001033
3  201207311030  0.0041  0.010000 -0.014150 -0.01725  0.040950
4  201207311030 -0.0041 -0.010000  0.014150  0.01725 -0.040950
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the index on the first column, use `transform` to get the mean for each group, while maintaining the shape, and again, use transform to do the subtraction, before resetting the index:

```
(arr
 .set_index(0)
 .transform(lambda df: df - df.groupby(level=0)
                              .transform("mean")
            )
 .reset_index()
 )
 
              0       1         2         3        4         5
0  201207310930  0.0033 -0.005567 -0.013267 -0.01140 -0.002133
1  201207310930  0.0051  0.003133  0.010533  0.00270  0.003167
2  201207310930 -0.0084  0.002433  0.002733  0.00870 -0.001033
3  201207311030  0.0041  0.010000 -0.014150 -0.01725  0.040950
4  201207311030 -0.0041 -0.010000  0.014150  0.01725 -0.040950
```

Another option would be to do the computation on the relevant columns separately, then `update` the original dataframe (Note that this overrides the original `arr` dataframe - you can make a copy of the dataframe before running update):

```
arr.update(arr.iloc[:, 1:] - arr.groupby(0).transform("mean"))

arr
           0       1         2         3        4         5
0  201207310930  0.0033 -0.005567 -0.013267 -0.01140 -0.002133
1  201207310930  0.0051  0.003133  0.010533  0.00270  0.003167
2  201207310930 -0.0084  0.002433  0.002733  0.00870 -0.001033
3  201207311030  0.0041  0.010000 -0.014150 -0.01725  0.040950
4  201207311030 -0.0041 -0.010000  0.014150  0.01725 -0.040950
```

Comment: do you know which would be the fastest for a ~50GB dataframe?

Comment: the last one is probably the fastest since it only calculates the mean once for each group, while the other options calculate the mean for each group for each element in each group?

Comment: for 50GB, probably would not think of Pandas

Comment: what would you recommend

Comment: dump it into sql? maybe use sqlite. or if you are familiar with R, you could use `data.table`. in python, you could use `pydatatable`. I'd first go for SQLite though, and I am assuming you have a bit of knowledge about SQL (this is similar to windows operations)